# Prophet forecast, high MSE

Tags: time-series, gam

i use prophet (facebook package) in monthly data, to predict car sales. 
the GAM seems to ignore (don't fit ) all higher values ( see the picture ).
that's give me a very higher MSE comparing to ARIMA model

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/encNS.png)

```
df <- data.frame(ds = seq(as.Date('1993-01-01'), as.Date('2017-06-01'),by = 'm'), y)
attach(df)
m <- prophet(df,weekly.seasonality = F, yearly.seasonality = T, seasonality.prior.scale = 12)
future <- make_future_dataframe(m, periods = 12, freq = 'm')
forecast <- predict(m, future)
tail(forecast[c('ds', 'yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper')])
plot(m, forecast)
```

Answer (score 2):

@alien_plutone,

You need to reduce variability in the time-series value (y) i.e. car sales value. Most time-series model expect stationary Time-Series values (y). I recommend using log-transformation on the time-series value before applying the prophet model. For example, introduce following line of code to make the time-series stationary.

#### NOTE:

log transformation to bring stationary in the time-series value (y). Most Time-series model require the input values (time series) to be stationary. A time series is said to be stationary if its trend and seasonality over time remains stable.

### `df['y'] <- np.log(df['y'])`

e.g. based on your code:

```
df <- data.frame(ds = seq(as.Date('1993-01-01'), as.Date('2017-06-01'),by = 'm'), y)
df['y'] <- np.log(df['y'])
m <- prophet(df,weekly.seasonality = F, yearly.seasonality = T, seasonality.prior.scale = 12)
future <- make_future_dataframe(m, periods = 12, freq = 'm')
forecast <- predict(m, future)
tail(forecast[c('ds', 'yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper')])
plot(m, forecast)
```

Please do let me know if this answer help you reduce the MSE. kindly use exp function to get forecasted value back to the original scale.

## Non-Stationary Time Series

[Click here to see plot of a non-stationary series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgcrQ.png)

## Stationary Time Series

[Click here to see plot of a Stationary series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5W4w.png)

Comment: you are right.. But as soon as I am taking log value the model is doing amazingly good. Is that justified.

Comment: Yes,  apt to reduce variability.